# using '$' in the replacing text / escaping it (RegEx-mode)

Tags: phpstorm

*my question is not about RegEx in general but about PhpStorm's search-replace-functionality with RegEx switched on.*

I use PhpStorm and I want to use the dollar-sign in the replacing text.

But when I do that using RegEx mode then $ becomes the special char for identifying back references.

So I have to escape it.

But neither \$ nor $$ is accepted by PhpStorm.

How do I escape $ in RegEx-mode?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

you have to use `\\$` for the replacing text.

searching for $ is done with `\$`.

Comment: Do you have any idea why that is, i.e. why is it not possible to enable replacement with `\$`, too?